# Get Array From List Of Rows?

Tags: java, mysql, arrays, row, fetch

I was curious on how to get a list of rows and add values from each row to an array in Java.

Here is what it looks like in PHP:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM names");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
// Get variables from this row and such
}
?>
```

I can't seem to find out how to do this in Java.

### Resolution Found

```
Statement sta = con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet res = sta.executeQuery("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM SalesLT.Customer");
while (res.next()) {
    String firstName = res.getString("FirstName");
    String lastName = res.getString("LastName");
    System.out.println("   " + firstName + " " + lastName);
}
```

Comment: There are a million JDBC tutorials on the web; start there, unless you're using an ORM library.

Comment: @DaveNewton Could you link me to one? I can't find any for this  task.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pure `JDBC` you can follow the example from the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/overview/index.html):

```
public void connectToAndQueryDatabase(String username, String password) {
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:myDriver:myDatabase", username, password);

    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT a, b, c FROM Table1");
    while (rs.next()) {
        int x = rs.getInt("a");
        String s = rs.getString("b");
        float f = rs.getFloat("c");
    }
}
```

But most people don't do this any more; you can, for example, use an ORM like [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) to abstract the database a bit.